# Что делать если забыл установить стандартные шаблоны в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Понятно, что можно переустановить. Но установка студии — задача часов на 5 (на моем компе, по крайне мере). Можно ли как-то поставить стандартные шаблоны после установки?

Под стандартными я понимаю, например, Console Application/WinForms Application и т. д.

Comment: осилите перевод https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185306(v=vs.100).aspx?

Comment: @LexHobbit Ваша ссылка не относится к делу. Там про сторонние шаблоны в старой студии, здесь про стандартные шаблоны в студии неизвестной версии.

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам таки нужно запустить установщик Visual Studio и проставить нужные галочки. Что-то мне подсказывает, что отсутствуют не только шаблоны, но вся инфраструктура, которая под них требуется — с трудом представляю, как можно поставить C# без шаблона консоли.

Остаётся надеяться, что доустановка обойдётся без переустановки уже установленного, то есть займёт меньше времени.

P. S. Начальная установка и настройка Visual Studio — это масшабное событие. Готовьтесь посвятить ему больше пяти часов, даже если у вас шустрый компьютер. :)

Comment: оки... буду пробовать... еще бы найти установочник(

Comment: В общем при запуске инсталлера, предлагается вариант "изменения"(думаю через Панель управления тоже можно запустить). Точно не помню куда тыкать, но и форум не для ламеров) Там все понятно.

Answer (score 0):

> Файл -> Создать -> Проект... (Ctrl+Shift+N)

В открывшемся окне жмем "Открыть установщик Visual Studio" и выбираем, что хотим доустановить.

[image: как доустановить пакеты в Visual Studio]

Comment: Пробовал, но по какой-то причине установщик Visual Studio не хотел обновляться.